# Angular routing for modules on the basis of service response

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing, angular-router

I am having trouble working on routing, for Angular 5. My requirement is as soon as the page loads the `Student user` will be redirected to `Students page` and `Teacher user` should be redirected to `Teacher page`.

For this, I have to make a service call as soon as the page loads and then decide which module to route to. Can anyone please guide me how to achieve this scenario? Any links/leads will be helpful.

Comment: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html

Answer (score 0):

In the main component, you can add `ngOnInit` life cycle and then load the data. Then depending on the parameter, you can redirect to whatever the page you want. For eg -

```
  ngOnInit() { 
    this.yourService.GetData()
        .subscribe(data => {
            if(data.id === student){
                this.router.navigate(['/student']);
            }else{ 
                this.router.navigate(['/Teacher']);
            }
        });
  }
```

add the router service as dependency injection in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use canActivate to navigate url based on the conditions.

```
path: 'admin',
component: AdminComponent,
canActivate: [RoleGuard],
data: {role: 'Admin'}
```